# Push Notification to IOS issue CodeName One

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, codenameone

I try to push notification from java server to IOS client
and i have this error(response from codename one server)

**{"error":"Failed to send push to APNS: com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake"}**

```
    String GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY = "********************************************";
    HttpsURLConnection connection;
    String url = "https://push.codenameone.com/push/push"; 
    String TOKEN = "******-****-*****-*****-**************";
    String URL_ENCODED_LINK_TO_YOUR_P12_FILE =
        "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/*/******************/Certificates.p12";
    String URL_ENCODED_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD = "******";

    String deviceId =
        "cn1-gcm-*******************************************************";
    String deviceId2 =
        "cn1-ios-***************************************************";
    String MESSAGE_BODY = "This notification  message coming from server";
    try {

        connection = (HttpsURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        String query =
            "token=" + TOKEN + "&device=" + deviceId + "&device=" +
            deviceId2 + "&type=1&auth=" + GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY +
            "&certPassword=" + URL_ENCODED_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD +
            "&cert=" + URL_ENCODED_LINK_TO_YOUR_P12_FILE + "&body=" +
            URLEncoder.encode(MESSAGE_BODY, "UTF-8") + "&production=false";
        try {
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("ResponseCode : " + connection.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("ResponsenMessage : " +
                           connection.getResponseMessage());
        BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        String result = "";
        System.out.println("Output  .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
            result += output + "\n";
        }

        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Output from codename one Server**

Response Code : 200

Response Message : OK

Output  ....

{"error":"Failed to send push to APNS: com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handshake exception would generally mean the [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) servers failed to connect due to a security issue. This probably means your P12 is incorrect.

Are you sure you used the right P12 file? Keep in mind that there are 2 push certificates (not to be confused with the 2 signing certificates) and only one of them should be used based on the value of the sandbox flag.

Did you use the certificate wizard?

Comment: yes i'm using valid P12 file but maybe my P12 link not understood by codename one server !!!! 

if you can tell me where i can put my P12 to accessed by codename one server . . 

and my P12 the same is P12 i used to send IOS build  (Codename One Server)

Comment: If your P12 file is the build certificate then that's your problem! iOS needs 4 certificates per app (when using push). The 2 build certificates have nothing to do with the push process. You need to create new P12 certificates specific to the app for push. This can be done with the certificate wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2195 and 2196 ports are disabled on either the server or client side which needs to be enabled for apple push notification.